# create a button and link to a page

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

this is my first time using html and im already stuck..

this is my code generated by the program

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">

    <label><span class="creamcustom">..</span> 

      <input type="submit" name="btnReadAles" id="btnReadAles" value="Read" />

    <span class="creamcustom">...... </span></label>

    <input type="submit" name="btnBuyAles" id="btnBuyAles" value="Buy Now" />

  </form>
```

now I want btn "btnReadAles" to link and open this page "read.html"

how do I do that, remember, I am still new so I do not know when to use eg.  (btw, I dont even know what it means...

thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<input type="submit" name="btnReadAles" id="btnReadAles" onclick='window.location.href="read.html"' value="Read" />
```

OR

```
<input type="submit" name="btnReadAles" id="btnReadAles" onclick='window.open("read.html")' value="Read" />
```

In FORM Action

```
<form action="read.html">
    <input type="submit" id="btnReadAles" value="Read">
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, just for intrest sake, why 2 different methods for the same thing, when is it appropriate to use windows.open and window.location.href, how do they differ?

Comment: ist one open in same tab second one open in new tab.if hepls mean accept as answer

Comment: i just tried the window.location.href, and it reloads the current webpage, however, the window.open DOES open the desired webpage

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it within a `form` element

```
<form action="http://some site.com/read.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Go to SOME SITE">
</form>
```

For more info see [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: could you just specify what does "wrap with a form element" mean? sorry if this is a stupid question... xD

Comment: For all your questions here are the answers http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp